# Swing Databinding for multiple JComponents

Tags: java, swing, data-binding

I'm pretty new to JAVA. I'm having a domain-model (containing the data) and I have a viewer-model (providing the GUI). Now I have several JLabels (or any other JComponents) on different windows, being bound to the same data-source in the domain-model.

I tried using beansbinding, but unfortunatly beansbinding seems not to support the binding of several widgets on a single source - only one widget is updated, the others are left untouched.

JGoodies is not possible for me, due to license questions.

Does anyone know another (free) Databinding-Project for SWING?

Thanks in advance
Joan

Comment: I don't know any alternative and wrote my own VMC-Databinding-Manager

Comment: probably something's wrong with the code you are not showing ;-) There's no restriction to the number of bindings on any property, so with proper setup, all labels should be updated on update of the bean property they are showing

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to the **Client Editor** sample application provided with NetBeans (New Project -> Samples / Java / Client Editor)

1. Open the main frame: ClientEditor.java
2. Add a label somewhere (in the corner bottom left for example)
3. Change its Binding (in Properties window) and use the same "formula" as the `usernameLabel` (at the right of "Client Info:") which is: `Form[${client.firstName} ${client.surname}]`

**Result:**
[image: Multi-binding is possible]